# (Xamarin - Android) Call a public method in the Activity class from another class?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android

I develop an app on Xamarin. I try to hide image when webview page loaded. I try different methods like call public function or access imageview from another class.

I read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836415/call-a-public-method-in-the-activity-class-from-another-class) but it doesn't work on Xamarin.

So I try something that

```
[Activity(Label = "XamarinWebView", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar", MainLauncher = true)]
     public class MainActivity : Activity
      {
         WebView app_view = null;
         WebSettings app_web_settings = null;
         WebChromeClient web_client;
         MyWebViewClient my_web_client;
         ImageView my_splash = null;

       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                app_view = FindViewById(Resource.Id.webViewapp) as WebView;
                my_web_client = new MyWebViewClient(this.ApplicationContext);
                app_view.SetWebViewClient(my_web_client);
                string app_url = "file:///android_asset/app_pages/test.html";
                app_view.LoadUrl(app_url);

                my_splash = FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageSplash) as ImageView;
 my_splash.SetImageDrawable(GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.splash));
            }

        public void HideSplash()
        {
             my_splash.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

    }
```

In this class I can get WebView page loading status.

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    { 
        Context context;
        public MyWebViewClient(Context _context) {
            this.context = _context;
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted(WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            **I need to change visible my_splash**
        }

    }
```

Comment: the approach you linked to WILL work in Xamarin - just pass in a ref to your MainActivity when you create your webclient.  Alternately, have your webclient raise an event when it completes, and your MainActivity can subscribe to it and responsd

Answer (score 0):

With Jason's advice I try something that and it works.

```
  public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
           .
           .
           .
           my_web_client = new MyWebViewClient(this);
           .
           .
           .
       }

    public void HideSplash()
        {
             my_splash.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
   }

 public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        MainActivity act;
        public MyWebViewClient(MainActivity activity)
        {
            this.act = activity;
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            act.Hide_Splash();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier approach to getting the activity from another class, which is also less error-prone and less likely to cause memory leaks would be to get the activity from the view context.

In your `MyWebViewClient` class:

```
public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
{
    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    (view.Context as MainActivity).HideSplash();
}
```

Or if you're not sure if the context will always be `MainActivity` you could use pattern matching which covers the null check:

```
public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
{
    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
    if(view.Context is MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        mainActivity.HideSplash();
    }
}
```

Using an approach like this is much easier to maintain down the road.